# Проблема с функцией поиска нужного типа в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в js. Мне нужно получить значение `true/false` в массиве объектов по определенному условию. Ниже моя попытка. Вопрос, почему `console.log(rightType(2))` выводит `false`. Возможно проблема в том что я не до конца разобрался с методом `reduce`

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 2,
  },

]

const rightType = (value) => data.reduce(
  (acc, {
    id,
    type
  }) => id === value && type === 2,
  false,
)

console.log(rightType(1)) //false 
console.log(rightType(2)) //false ????
console.log(rightType(3)) //true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос, почему `console.log(rightType(2))` выводит `false`

Потому что колбек функция в `reduce` всегда возвращает `false`...

> Возможно проблема в том что я не до конца разобрался с методом reduce

Думаю что именно в этом проблема. Поскольку это метод ту не совсем уместен.
Тут более подойдет метод `some()`.
https://doka.guide/js/array-some/

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 2,
  },

]

const rightType = value => data.some(({id, type}) => id === value && type === 2)

console.log(rightType(1)) //false 
console.log(rightType(2)) //true
console.log(rightType(3)) //true
```